# Git merge only fixes, no merge from other branches

Tags: git, merge, branch

We're in a complex situation. We've got this king of repository:

```
        C1      C4              C5
devel   *---*---*---*-----------*---------
              \_____
                    \    C2    C3      
fix-ie  *--*---------*----*----*-------*---
                     M1                 \___
                                            \
testing *----*-------------------------------*---
                                             M2
```

As you can see, devel is merged inside fix-ie branch.

Problem is that "testing" branch should not have "devel" commits (we don't want C1) but we need to merge fix-ie in "testing" to have only C2 and C3 commits

If I do:

```
git checkout testing
git merge fix-ie
```

I will have the M1 merge in my testing branch... So C1 commit is found in our testing branch. That's not what we want.

How to avoid this ?

Remember that I simplified example, there are lot of merges, lot of commits in our fix-ie and devel branches.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a separate `fix-ie` branch that excludes the merge commits from your `devel` branch. You can then merge that branch to your `testing` branch.

You can search your reflogs using `git reflog show -all` to find your merge commits from the `devel` branch that you want to ignore.

Comment: But the problem is that fix-ie and testing are branches from "devel"... devel is the main branch, testing is branch from devel with some fixes for the testing environment. devel is made for the next releases. There are a lot of merge in fix-ie (coming from devel)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found a solution.

Getting the first merge SHA, named "123abc" for example. I can do:

```
git rev-list --no-merges --reverse --topo-order debug-ie ^123abc
```

Then each line is a commit, but no merge are in the list.

So the way I can do is:

```
for SHA in $(git rev-list --no-merges --reverse --topo-order debug-ie ^123abc); do
    git cherry-pick $SHA
done
```

If I'm wrong, tell me... but it seems to be a nice idea.

Comment: Well you are actually duplicating all the commits, that is not always the best idea